# R - left_join dataframe with loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, left-join

my dataframe x looks like this

```
    id 
1   42
```

My second data.frame z is:

```
   id amoumt     date
1  42      3  2013-09
2  42      8  2013-09
3  42      1  2011-09
```

The goals are:

- find lowest and highest date
- calculate amount for each month (if there are more amounts from one id and same, calculate it into one row)
- create column with date and append it into the x dataframe (keep in mind that in my project range will be more that 10 years).

I have created this code:

```
dates <- as.character(seq(as.Date(min(z$date), max(z$date), by=c("months"))))
```

It finds first and last date. And then I have this loop, which do not works:

```
for (d in dates) {
  z %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>%
    setNames(c(names(.)[1], paste("in", format(as.Date(d), "%Y-%m"), sep=" "))) %>%
    left_join(
      .,
      x,
      by=c("id")        )
}
```

Result should look like this:

```
   id 2011-09    2013-09
1  42       0         11
2  42       1          0
```

Comment: `xtabs(amoumt~.,merge(x,aggregate(amoumt~.,dat,sum)))`?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  inner_join(z) %>%
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  filter(which.min(date) || which.max(date)) %>%
  summarize(amount = sum(amount),
            row = max(row)) %>%
  spread(date, amount) %>%
  select(-row)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   id [1]
     id `2011-09` `2013-09`
  <int>     <int>     <int>
1    42        NA        11
2    42         1        NA
```

**Data:**

```
x = structure(list(id = 42L), .Names = "id", class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")

z = structure(list(id = c(42L, 42L, 42L), amount = c(3L, 8L, 1L), 
    date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2011-09", "2013-09"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "amount", "date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr` and `zoo` can be achieved by converting `date` column to `yearmon` type. Join both `z` and `x` together in order to perform operations for `min` and `max`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

z %>% mutate(date = as.yearmon(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  right_join(x, by="id") %>%
  group_by(id, date) %>%
  summarise(amoumt = sum(amoumt)) %>%  #Monthly sum
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(minDate = min(date), maxDate = max(date))

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# id date          amoumt minDate       maxDate      
# <int> <S3: yearmon>  <int> <S3: yearmon> <S3: yearmon>
# 1    42 Sep 2011           1 Sep 2011      Sep 2013     
# 2    42 Sep 2013          11 Sep 2011      Sep 2013
```

**Data:**

```
z <- read.table(text = 
"id amoumt     date
1  42      3  2013-09
2  42      8  2013-09
3  42      1  2011-09",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x <- read.table(text = 
"id 
1   42",  
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```