# How to implement left_Join with Loops

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes, and I'm trying to merge them by common column names.
for example :

```
s=left_join(df1,df2,by=Common_names1)
```

**My question is:**

how can i implement `left_join` with `for loop`, `while loop` and `if condition` only once ?

Thanks

Comment: This question is rather broad - can you narrow it down or name an example usecase for this?

Comment: Can you explain more about your goals? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to merge vectors that has common columns, The only exception is that i must use WHILE, IF and FOR only once

Comment: Here you can find a `left_join` and with `for loop`: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50865512/r-left-join-dataframe-with-loop>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of left_join. But it uses 5 for loops, 0 while loops, and 0 if statements. It takes as arguments the two data frames, with the first one acting as the column's base, and the name of the column by which the tables should be left-joined.

```
ljoin=function(x, y, co) {
  df=data.frame()
  sect=setdiff(intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)), co)
  for (i in length(sect)) {
    x=rename(x, "{sect[i]}.x":=all_of(sect[i]))
    y=rename(y, "{sect[i]}.y":=all_of(sect[i]))
  }
  sepa=setdiff(x[,co], y[,co])
  df=filter(x, x[,co] %in% sepa)
  diff=setdiff(colnames(y), colnames(x))
  for (colname in diff) {
    df=mutate(df, "{colname}":=NA)
  }
  sect=intersect(x[,co], y[,co])
  for (i in 1:length(sect)) {
    j=filter(x, x[,co]==sect[i])
    k=filter(y, y[,co]==sect[i])
    creation=data.frame()
    for (l in 1:nrow(j)) {
      for (m in 1:nrow(k)) {
        n=select(k[m,], -all_of(co))
        ro=bind_cols(j[l,], n)
        df=bind_rows(df, ro)
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}
```

Check

```
> x=data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,3,4,5), c=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> y=data.frame(a=c(1,2,6,7,8), b=c(1,2,3,4,5), d=c(1,2,3,4,5))
> ljoin(x,y,"a")
  a b.x c b.y  d
1 3   3 3  NA NA
2 4   4 4  NA NA
3 5   5 5  NA NA
4 1   1 1   1  1
5 2   2 2   2  2
> left_join(x,y, by="a")
  a b.x c b.y  d
1 1   1 1   1  1
2 2   2 2   2  2
3 3   3 3  NA NA
4 4   4 4  NA NA
5 5   5 5  NA NA
```